# Class Constructor in Gui of Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I am currently trying to create a gui which connects serial port when clicked button. This button calls a class constructor method and creates an object which will be called in different ways when other buttons clicked.For example:

```
    function button1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    val1=get(handles.edittext1,value);
    val1=get(handles.edittext1,value);
    exmple = Example(val1,val2);%connects to serial and creates object
    %which allows to send data to port
    function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    x=get(handles.slider1,value);
    exmple.setVal(s);
```

So how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share variables between functions inside a GUI, you should use `guidata`. In my experience, the best way is :

- Initialize the variables in the GUI_OpeningFcn :

  ```
  handles.exmpl = []; 
  guidata(hObject, handles); % update handles
  ```
- In your button_CallbackFcn:

  ```
  handles.exmpl = Example(val1, val2);
  guidata(hObject, handles);
  ```
- In slider_CallbackFcn:

  ```
  handles.exmpl.setVal(x);
  guidata(hObject, handles);
  ```